# How do I link to SDL2 in Android Studio from a native activity based project?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, sdl, sdl-2

How do I setup Gradle in Android Studio to find `libSDL2.so` (or any other .so library)?

- I've placed the `.so` files in `app/src/main/jniLibs` under their corresponding target directory (i.e `/armeabi/libSDL2.so`, `/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so` etc).
- I've added `SDL2` to the `CMakeFiles.txt` by the other libraries included in NDK.

When building the linker cannot find `-lSDL2` `(...\ld: error: cannot find -lSDL2)`

I suppose there is something I need to add to the gradle script, but I cannot find out what and where.

*Notes:*
The project is a pure NativeActivity project.
Android Studio is version 3.0

Comment: Same problem. You find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Too late but it may be useful for others. I've added `libSDL2.so` to my android project recently. Since I had this issue and found the solution, I post my solution here for others. I did the following step:

1. Copy `libSDL2.so` into `app/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so`
2. Add the following lines to `src/main/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(
    SDL2
    SHARED
    IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
    SDL2
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2.so
)

target_link_libraries(
    your-lib PUBLIC
    SDL2
)
```